# How to link a project to private git hub repo?

Tags: android, git, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am currently using flutter in Android studio and was wondering how to link a project to a private repo in android studio?

Btw this is a condensed self answer to myself.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Flutter or Dart.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd <project folder>
git init
git add .
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/project.git
git fetch origin
git commit -m "My first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Then in android studio

VCS -> Git -> Push